# Not all optional NSTextViewDelegate methods being fired (SWIFT)

Tags: macos, swift, tooltip, nstextview

This is an OSX SWIFT project

The NSTextViewDelegate protocol defines a bunch of optional methods. I know I've correctly wired-up the delegate because I receive this notification.

```
func textViewDidChangeSelection(notification: NSNotification)
```

However, other methods I need are never being fired. Specifically, I'm trying to implement custom tooltip behaviour in a textview, but the following are never fired, even though a tooltip has been set and is being displayed.

```
func textView(textView: NSTextView, willDisplayToolTip tooltip: String, forCharacterAtIndex characterIndex: Int) -> String?


func textView(textView: NSTextView, doCommandBySelector commandSelector: Selector) -> Bool
```

There are other optional methods of interest as well, so the list above is just illustrative.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is your delegate object a subclass of NSObject?  If it's not then the NSTextView has no way of finding optional methods.

Comment: @David - yes. I've tried setting the delegate to instances of an NSWindowController for example, as well as the Application delegate. In each case,as part of testing, the textViewDidChangeSelection method is fired as expected, but the others not.